# How to prevent overriding a superclass by a subclass using final method PHP

Tags: php

I am just learning php and I came across final method, it says it can prevent overriding of a method in the superclass by a subclass. I would like you to please give me some examples of this as the textbook am using didn't explain enough.

Comment: Then change the textbook, isnt it simple?

Comment: A final class is one which cannot be extended http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php

Comment: Look here for the final keyword, explains everything: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about not having looked at the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php) before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example if you have a superclass let's say Foo. Containing a `final` method called : bar

```
class Foo
{
    final public function bar()
    {
        //Do action A
    }
}
```

Now we have a subclass, let's say called Foo2, which extends from Foo.

```
class Foo2 extends Foo
{
    //This class will not be able to override the bar() function.
}
```

As the `final` keyword indicated that the function can not be overridden, "Action A" will alway be the stuff the function does, it can not be changed in the subclasses.